# JQuery textbox autocomplete conflicts with Ajax Calendar Extender

Tags: ajax, jquery, calendarextender

I have a asp.net page with uses a JQuery and a web service to perform the autocomplete when the user types a name in a textbox.

This has been working well until I added an Ajax Calendar Extender. Since then, the page does not seem to post pack or use the web service for the textbox autocomplete.

Is there a problem using both technologies together? If not, what is the easiest way to make them work together?

Thank you,

Comment: Appears some js error when you type in your textbox?

Comment: Can you share with us what error is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue and it was 3rd party component conflicting with the calendar extender.

Thank you,